# How do you put in a graphical abstract?

Tags: floats, abstract, article

I tried adding figure environment inside the abstract area but it generates an error. How do I add a graphical abstract as well as a textual one?

Comment: Perhaps just use `\includegraphics` without the figure environment. Do you need a caption?

Comment: What class are you using? It works fine for me in the article and report classes. Can you show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that exhibits this error?

Comment: Nicola is correct. Not suse how to make them appear next to each other; I had to use `\centering` to get them on separate lines.

Comment: @Elliot Can you edit your question to include a MWE or make a self-answer? At this point, I don't think that this question is of any help to anyone reading this. As such, this could be closed as too localized.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Seems like your comment is the (simple) right answer, why don’t you make a real answer out of it?!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `\includegraphics` without the `figure` environment. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
One possible method:

{\centering
\includegraphics{test-img}
\par
}

This is a sample abstract with the image centred on the line above. 
Another method below.

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Here's another paragraph with the image on the right of the text.
It's done by putting this paragraph in a minipage environment with a
top-aligned image next to it.
\end{minipage}
\vtop{%
  \vskip-1ex
  \hbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{test-img}%
  }%
}%
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

See [Top-aligning imported graphics](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-topgraph) for an explanation about the `\vtop` stuff.

Comment: Isn't `\begin{center}\includegraphics[...]{...}\end{center}` easier than the first method?

Comment: @egreg It depends if you want the extra vertical space.

Comment: I'd want it. :)